# AlarmReceiver not waking up app

Tags: android, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

With the following code, the `AlarmReceiver.onReceive()` is not called when it should be after the app is killed manually (to simulate the OS killing the app on a whim).

What must I do so that the AlarmReceiver still works after the OS kills it?

Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="abc.def.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        />
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void setupAlarm(Context context, int intervalMS)  {
        this.interval = interval;

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        updateTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), intervalMS, recurringDownload);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Alarm", "hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: From where you are calling method `setupAlarm`?

Answer (score 0):

When you kill it manually, you're putting the app into the forced stop state.  That stops all Receivers and Services until you start it by hand again.  That's not the same as being killed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Normal process termination(by OS) does not cancel scheduled AlarmManager events. So, the alarms would still work after OS kills the process.

If you are manually force-closing the app, your alarms are unregistered. And, on Android 3.1+, you have to manually launch one of the activities to register them again.
So by killing the app manually you are not exactly simulating the OS killing the app

Answer (score 0):

`android:exported="false"` means you don't allow your app to receive any events from system. Change it to `true`

One more thing, make sure you call `setupAlarm` in `Context`

From the documentation of google

> Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and "false" if not. If "false", the only messages the broadcast receiver can receive are those sent by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID.
>   The default value depends on whether the broadcast receiver contains intent filters. The absence of any filters means that it can be invoked only by Intent objects that specify its exact class name. This implies that the receiver is intended only for application-internal use (since others would not normally know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the broadcast receiver is intended to receive intents broadcast by the system or other applications, so the default value is "true".
>
> This attribute is not the only way to limit a broadcast receiver's external exposure. You can also use a permission to limit the external entities that can send it messages (see the permission attribute).

Answer (score 0):

All is accordingly but in the code may be you have not called your **setupAlarm()** method in **onRecieve()**.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void setupAlarm(Context context, int intervalMS)  {
        this.interval = interval;

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        updateTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), intervalMS, recurringDownload);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Alarm", "hello world!");
        setupAlarm(context,2000);//May be this line is missing.
    }
}
```